# Getting data from complex html tag with Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML data:

```
<div class="display-info">
    <div class="record-icon pubtype"><span class="pubtype-icon pt-academicJournal" title="Academic Journal"> </span>
        <p class="caption">Academic Journal</p>
    </div>By: Stein, Mark. <strong>Organization Studies</strong>. 2007, Vol. 28 Issue 8, p1223-1241. 19p. Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in further <strong>contagion</strong> of relationships such as those among employees and between employees and customers. This may also result in workers retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the body with emotions. [ABSTRACT FROM AUTHOR] DOI: 10.1177/0170840607079527. (<cite>AN: 26198405</cite>)
    <p class="subjectResults"><strong>Subjects:
    </strong>Industrial relations; Personnel management; Customer relations; Corporate image; Public relations; Consumer behavior; Sales personnel; Administration of Human Resource Programs (except Education, Public Health, and Veterans' Affairs Programs); Human Resources Consulting Services; Public Relations Agencies; Psychoanalysis; Social interaction</p><span class="record-additional"><span class="item add-to-folder"><a class="folder-toggle item-not-in-folder" data-folder='{"db":"bth","uiTerm":"26198405","uiTag":"AN","ebookFormat":"false","abookFormat":"false","title":"Toxicity and the Unconscious Experience of the Body at the Employee--Customer Interface. ","resultID":"50","doid":"","segid":""}' data-isaddtofolder="true" data-itemid="50" href="#" id="add_50" name="addToFolder" title="To print, e-mail, or save multiple items">Add to folder</a> <a class="folder-toggle item-in-folder" data-folder='{"db":"bth","uiTerm":"26198405","uiTag":"AN","ebookFormat":"false","abookFormat":"false","title":"Toxicity and the Unconscious Experience of the Body at the Employee--Customer Interface. ","resultID":"50","doid":"","segid":""}' data-isaddtofolder="false" data-itemid="50" href="#" id="added_50" style="display: none;" title="Remove result from folder">Remove from folder</a></span><span class="result-list-cite-ref-label"><a data-title="Cited References" href="javascript:__doLinkPostBack('','sl~~ref||su~~50','_top');" id="references50" title="Cited References">Cited References: (92) </a></span><span class="result-list-cite-link"><a data-title="Times Cited in this Database" href="javascript:__doLinkPostBack('','sl~~cit||su~~50','_top');" id="citations50" title="Times Cited in this Database">Times Cited in this Database: (20) </a></span> </span>
    <div class="record-formats-wrapper externalLinks"><span><span class="custom-link"><a class="ils-link" href="/ehost/SmartLink/OpenIlsLink?sid=42487fcc-c655-469f-b8ed-2802260b3983@sessionmgr102&amp;vid=15&amp;sl=smartlink&amp;st=ilslink_new&amp;sv=sdbn%253Dbth%2526pbt%253DAcademic%2520Journal%2526issn%253D01708406%2526ttl%253DOrganization%252520Studies%2526stp%253DC%2526asi%253DY%2526ldc%253DCheck%252520full%252520text%252520availability%2526lna%253DFull%252520Text%252520Finder%252520%25252D%252520INSEAD%2526lca%253DfullText%2526lo%255Fan%253D26198405&amp;su=http%3A%2F%2Fresolver%2Eebscohost%2Ecom%2Fopenurl%3Fcustid%3Ds8362180%26group%3Dmain%26authtype%3Dip%2Cuid%26sid%3DEBSCO%3Abth%26genre%3Darticle%26issn%3D01708406%26ISBN%3D%26volume%3D28%26issue%3D8%26date%3D20070801%26spage%3D1223%26pages%3D1223%2D1241%26title%3DOrganization%20Studies%26atitle%3DToxicity%2520and%2520the%2520Unconscious%2520Experience%2520of%2520the%2520Body%2520at%2520the%2520Employee%2D%2DCustomer%2520Interface%2E%26aulast%3DStein%252C%2520Mark%26id%3DDOI%3A10%2E1177%2F0170840607079527" id="linkILSLink50_1" onblur="self.status='';return true" onfocus="self.status='check full text availability.';return true" onmouseout="self.status='';return true" onmouseover="self.status='check full text availability.';return true" target="_new" title="check full text availability."><img align="middle" alt="check full text availability." border="0" class="icon-image" data-defer-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/customers/2023/images/logo-INSEAD_blanc-sur-vert_250.jpg" id="imgILSLink50_1" src="https://if.ebsco-content.com/interfacefiles/17.232.0.2749/blank.gif"/>Check full text availability</a></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get `By: Stein, Mark.`  and `Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in further <strong>contagion</strong> of relationships such as those among employees and between employees and customers. This may also result in workers retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the body with emotions.`

With `soup.select(".display-info")[0].text` I get

```
 Academic JournalBy: Stein, Mark. Organization Studies. 2007, Vol. 28 Issue 8, p1223-1241. 19p. Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in further contagion of relationships such as those among employees and between employees and customers. This may also result in workers retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the body with emotions. [ABSTRACT FROM AUTHOR] DOI: 10.1177/0170840607079527. (AN: 26198405)Subjects:
    Industrial relations; Personnel management; Customer relations; Corporate image; Public relations; Consumer behavior; Sales personnel; Administration of Human Resource Programs (except Education, Public Health, and Veterans' Affairs Programs); Human Resources Consulting Services; Public Relations Agencies; Psychoanalysis; Social interactionAdd to folder Remove from folderCited References: (92) Times Cited in this Database: (20)  Check full text availability
```

Comment: What are you trying to find and on what element? Also could you try to edit your html so that it is more readable? I was attempting to fix it for you but it seems extremely hard.

Comment: html looks like this unfortunately but I can add a link and specify the html tags

Comment: I edited the html

Comment: This would not be a bad place to consider using a regular expression to extract the data

Comment: Thanks for the edit. My bad you did say what you needed.

Comment: Can you show what you get with `soup.select(".display-info")` and possibly also `soup.select(".display-info").text` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task is better to use `re` and `bs4` together.

If variable `txt` contains HTML text from the question, then this script:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

txt = soup.select_one('.display-info').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')

author = re.findall(r'By:.*', txt)[0]
abstract = re.findall(r'Abstract:.*?(?=\[ABSTRACT FROM AUTHOR\])', txt, flags=re.S)[0]

from textwrap import wrap
print(author)
print(*wrap(abstract.replace('\n', ' ')), sep='\n')

# or in case Python2 just:
# print author
# print abstract
```

Prints:

```
By: Stein, Mark.
Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a
variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture
certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service
employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and
using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to
organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of
toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from
customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that
they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious
experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in
further contagion of relationships such as those among employees and
between employees and customers. This may also result in workers
retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward
spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large
parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The
implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the
theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface
with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the
body with emotions.
```

Comment: @edyvedy13 Syntax error? Are you using Python2? You can just `print author` and `print abstract` without the `wrap`, I used it just to pretty print here.

Comment: No but I think the problem is (abstract.replace('\n', ' ')), sep='\n')

Comment: it works, at the end I will save them to csv, do you think it will create a problem ?

Comment: @edyvedy13 I don't think so. Just use proper delimiter and quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use following Regular expression.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html='''<div class="display-info">
    <div class="record-icon pubtype"><span class="pubtype-icon pt-academicJournal" title="Academic Journal"> </span>
        <p class="caption">Academic Journal</p>
    </div>By: Stein, Mark. <strong>Organization Studies</strong>. 2007, Vol. 28 Issue 8, p1223-1241. 19p. Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in further <strong>contagion</strong> of relationships such as those among employees and between employees and customers. This may also result in workers retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the body with emotions. [ABSTRACT FROM AUTHOR] DOI: 10.1177/0170840607079527. (<cite>AN: 26198405</cite>)
    <p class="subjectResults"><strong>Subjects:
    </strong>Industrial relations; Personnel management; Customer relations; Corporate image; Public relations; Consumer behavior; Sales personnel; Administration of Human Resource Programs (except Education, Public Health, and Veterans' Affairs Programs); Human Resources Consulting Services; Public Relations Agencies; Psychoanalysis; Social interaction</p><span class="record-additional"><span class="item add-to-folder"><a class="folder-toggle item-not-in-folder" data-folder='{"db":"bth","uiTerm":"26198405","uiTag":"AN","ebookFormat":"false","abookFormat":"false","title":"Toxicity and the Unconscious Experience of the Body at the Employee--Customer Interface. ","resultID":"50","doid":"","segid":""}' data-isaddtofolder="true" data-itemid="50" href="#" id="add_50" name="addToFolder" title="To print, e-mail, or save multiple items">Add to folder</a> <a class="folder-toggle item-in-folder" data-folder='{"db":"bth","uiTerm":"26198405","uiTag":"AN","ebookFormat":"false","abookFormat":"false","title":"Toxicity and the Unconscious Experience of the Body at the Employee--Customer Interface. ","resultID":"50","doid":"","segid":""}' data-isaddtofolder="false" data-itemid="50" href="#" id="added_50" style="display: none;" title="Remove result from folder">Remove from folder</a></span><span class="result-list-cite-ref-label"><a data-title="Cited References" href="javascript:__doLinkPostBack('','sl~~ref||su~~50','_top');" id="references50" title="Cited References">Cited References: (92) </a></span><span class="result-list-cite-link"><a data-title="Times Cited in this Database" href="javascript:__doLinkPostBack('','sl~~cit||su~~50','_top');" id="citations50" title="Times Cited in this Database">Times Cited in this Database: (20) </a></span> </span>
    <div class="record-formats-wrapper externalLinks"><span><span class="custom-link"><a class="ils-link" href="/ehost/SmartLink/OpenIlsLink?sid=42487fcc-c655-469f-b8ed-2802260b3983@sessionmgr102&amp;vid=15&amp;sl=smartlink&amp;st=ilslink_new&amp;sv=sdbn%253Dbth%2526pbt%253DAcademic%2520Journal%2526issn%253D01708406%2526ttl%253DOrganization%252520Studies%2526stp%253DC%2526asi%253DY%2526ldc%253DCheck%252520full%252520text%252520availability%2526lna%253DFull%252520Text%252520Finder%252520%25252D%252520INSEAD%2526lca%253DfullText%2526lo%255Fan%253D26198405&amp;su=http%3A%2F%2Fresolver%2Eebscohost%2Ecom%2Fopenurl%3Fcustid%3Ds8362180%26group%3Dmain%26authtype%3Dip%2Cuid%26sid%3DEBSCO%3Abth%26genre%3Darticle%26issn%3D01708406%26ISBN%3D%26volume%3D28%26issue%3D8%26date%3D20070801%26spage%3D1223%26pages%3D1223%2D1241%26title%3DOrganization%20Studies%26atitle%3DToxicity%2520and%2520the%2520Unconscious%2520Experience%2520of%2520the%2520Body%2520at%2520the%2520Employee%2D%2DCustomer%2520Interface%2E%26aulast%3DStein%252C%2520Mark%26id%3DDOI%3A10%2E1177%2F0170840607079527" id="linkILSLink50_1" onblur="self.status='';return true" onfocus="self.status='check full text availability.';return true" onmouseout="self.status='';return true" onmouseover="self.status='check full text availability.';return true" target="_new" title="check full text availability."><img align="middle" alt="check full text availability." border="0" class="icon-image" data-defer-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/customers/2023/images/logo-INSEAD_blanc-sur-vert_250.jpg" id="imgILSLink50_1" src="https://if.ebsco-content.com/interfacefiles/17.232.0.2749/blank.gif"/>Check full text availability</a></span></span>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
divtext=soup.find('div',class_='display-info')
print(re.findall("By:?\s.*Mark.",divtext.text)[0])
print(re.findall("Abstract:?\s.*\[",divtext.text)[0][:-1])
```

**Output**:

```
By: Stein, Mark.
Abstract: While the literature on front-line service work utilizes a variety of productive images, I argue that these images do not capture certain of the more problematic experiences of front-line service employees. Drawing on words used by these workers themselves, and using concepts from psychoanalysis and its application to organizational dynamics, I therefore propose a new image, that of toxicity. I argue that — especially when under severe pressure from customers — front-line workers may have the unconscious fantasy that they have been polluted by toxic substances. The unconscious experience of the entry of toxic material is likely to result in further contagion of relationships such as those among employees and between employees and customers. This may also result in workers retaliating against customers by exacting revenge on them. A downward spiralling of relationships may follow, with the result that large parts of the work environment are experienced as toxic. The implications for theory are explored. In conclusion, I argue that the theme of toxicity helps us connect the employee-customer interface with a deep reservoir of primordial human experience that links the body with emotions.
```